# How do I get the default redirect to login URL from the web.config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My web.config has this:

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/" />
    </authentication>
```

Is there a nice way to get this loginUrl in the MVC code as a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you search the web for for "asp.net get loginurl from web.config", you'll [find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.loginurl(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl
```